# MVC Crystal report viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I am trying to bind the data to the crystal report viewer through the view by using MVC architecture I am getting an error like "Error programming" message on the crystal report viewer.  What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that Crystal Viewer works in MVC? I would assume it won't work since it is (probably) an asp.net (not MVC) control.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report does not work with MVC. If you want to show Crystal Report with your MVC application, you have to add an `.aspx` page, and then you can use Crystal Report with your MVC application.